# How to add a Restful controller in a Zend module

Tags: rest, zend-framework, routes, controllers

I'm actually working on a zend framework 2 application which should render two sorts of View :

- a view model
- a json model

I would include the restful controller in my module but I don't understand if it's possible or recommended.

If someone has been already confronted to a same case, does he could bring me some explanations because I'm searching an answer since 2 days fruitlessly.

In my module.config.php I have :

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Role\Controller\Role' => 'Role\Controller\RoleController',
            'Role\Controller\RoleRest' => 'Role\Controller\RoleRestController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'role' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/role[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Role\Controller\Role',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'role-rest' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/role-rest[/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'id'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Role\Controller\RoleRest',
                        'action'     => 'getList',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'role' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

and when i try to get myApplication.localhost/role-rest, the page displays the following message :

"The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.

Controller:

Role\Controller\RoleRest"

I resolve the problem with a simple change in the id's regex constraint :

'constraints' => array(
     'id'     => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
),

Comment: Please include your code, error you have encoutered, what you expected versus what you got, by editing your question.

Comment: I just don't understand why the controller is unable to be dispatched by the router. Should I create a specific strategy ?